# Основы C++ для начинающих

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, подскажите книги где описаны основы C++ для начинающих. Именно основы.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и другая литература по С++](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1)

Answer (score 3):

Основы С++ - это Си. Пользуйтесь поиском хотя бы по этому сайту. Ваш вопрос далеко не уникален, повторятся, как я вижу, никто уже не хочет =)

Comment: Или лучше [гуглом](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8+c%2B%2B+site%3Ahashcode.ru): [[1]](/questions/180470/), [[2]](/questions/269743/), [[3]](/questions/271861/), [[4]](/questions/173476/), [[5]](/questions/184539/), [[6]](/questions/29229/), [[7]](/questions/156202/), [[8]](/questions/240356/), ...

Comment: Не согласен. Основы С++ - это основы С++. А Си - это Си.

Comment: @skegg аргументный аргумент.